# How to create a materialized view using datastax library

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I'm using `SchemaBuilder` to create table schemas and Indexes, but I don't see an option to create materialized views

Is it possible to create materialized views using the `SchemaBuilder`

```
import com.datastax.driver.core._
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder
import com.datastax.driver.core.schemabuilder.{Create, SchemaBuilder, SchemaStatement}


val table = SchemaBuilder.createTable(keyspace, tableName).ifNotExists()
    .addPartitionKey("key", DataType.varchar())
     .......
    .addColumn("more columns", DataType.bigint())

// Want to create a materialized view on table
```

Comment: Materialized Views are considered experimental, so better avoid using them http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201710.mbox/%3CetPan.59f24f38.438f4e99.74dc@apple.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the driver there is no `SchemaBuilder` for materialized views, but this *could* be improved in the next versions (although I don't know about plans).

But you can just execute `session.execute('CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...);` just like a normal command - you only need to have syntax checked via `cqlsh`, or something like.

Comment: Coincidentally, we started implementing a schema builder for materialized views in the 4.x driver this week :)!  I wrote some documentation for it yesterday which can be found on the PR: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/java1515/manual/query_builder/schema/materialized_view . It will be a few months before we release 4.x, but this should be included.

Comment: @AndyTolbert any news?

Comment: It's supported in the driver 4.x: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/query_builder/schema/materialized_view/

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the Python package. You are free to try out [my gist](https://gist.github.com/caniko/c52bc97a3b93e1f2d38b655d7f5c15ae) in the meantime!